# How to call solr to optimize using java code

Tags: java, solr

Not under shell 
I want to call the optimize using Java code and get notification when the optimize process is finished.

Comment: I've fixed the obvious typos, but your question is inscrutable.  You might be asking whether you can invoke a Java optimizer and get to know when it is complete, but it could be something else too.

Answer (score 3):

Just fire a request to `/solr/update?optimize=true` from anywhere/anything that has access to the Solr server, e.g:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update?optimize=true'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj), you call the [optimize](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html#optimize()) method of the class [CommonsHttpSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer.html).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734543/how-to-know-when-solr-optimize-is-done) about how to know when the optimize is done.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be little more specific about your requirement,anyway
Here is how i optimize the solr using solrj EmbeddedSolrServer,

```
SolrServer server = CacheServer.getCacheInstance().getServer();
    try {
        server.optimize();
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

For more details about [optimize](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html#optimize%28%29)