# Solr Trigger Optimize And Check Progress From Java Code

Tags: java, optimization, solr, solrj

From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744652/how-to-call-solr-to-optimize-using-java-code) there are two ways to trigger solr optimize from Java code. 
Either sending an http request, or using solrj api.
But how to check the progress of it?
Say, an api which returns the progress of optimize in percentage 
or strings like RUNNING/COMPLETED/FAILED.
Is there such an api?

Comment: Facing the same problem here.. Have you found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, optimize() in solrj api is a sync method. 
Here is what I used to monitor the optimization progress.

```
CloudSolrClient client = null;
    try {
        client = new CloudSolrClient(zkClientUrl);
        client.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);
        m_logger.info("Explicit optimize of collection " + collectionName);
        long optimizeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        UpdateResponse optimizeResponse = client.optimize();

        for (Object object : optimizeResponse.getResponse()) {
            m_logger.info("Solr optimizeResponse" + object.toString());
        }
        if (optimizeResponse != null) {
            m_logger.info(String.format(
                    " Elapsed Time(in ms) - %d, QTime (in ms) - %d",
                    optimizeResponse.getElapsedTime(),
                    optimizeResponse.getQTime()));
        }
        m_logger.info(String.format(
                "Time spent on Optimizing a collection %s :"
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - optimizeStart)
                        / 1000 + " seconds", collectionName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        m_logger.error("Failed during explicit optimize on collection "
                + collectionName, e);
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Failed to close CloudSolrClient connection.", e);
            }
            client = null;
        }
    }
```